# Can I plot multiple statistics for one metric on the same axis in a Cloudwatch Dashboard?

Tags: dashboard, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to look at the min, max, and average statistics for each time interval for a particular custom metric. In this case it's the size of each file my system is ingesting. Currently I can do this in a CloudWatch Dashboard with three separate widgets, one for each statistic:

[image]

I'd really prefer to have at least two curves on the same axis. I know how to put two different curves on one widget, but that only appears to support having two different metrics, with the same aggregation function applied.

Interestingly, in the Lambda monitoring view, AWS provides just such a plot for Invocation Duration:
[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Under Actions column, there is a button to Duplicate a metric. Just click on it, it'll add the a copy of that metric to same graph. Then you can tweak Statistic for this copy. E.g. below I have min, max and avg of CPUUtilization.

[image]

Comment: does anyone know how to do the same in CDK?

Answer (score -1):

One workaround would be to create duplicate dummy metrics for the same data, then overlay them. The only problem is you'd still be stuck hard-coding the statistic for each curve, so the Average of the Min metric would work out to the min of the average. Not worth it.